# Access Exchange shared folder via powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to access a public Exchange folder from my machine using PowerShell. I've found a guide saying that Get-PublicFolder is what I need, but I get this error:

```
The term 'Get-PublicFolder' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term
and try again.
```

Another guide suggests to add the exchange management snapin before calling it

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
```

but again i get no luck as it is not installed on my PC. So, what's the easiest way to cccess a public Exchange folder via PowerShell? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your machine and the Exchange server have PowerShell v2 remoting enabled then you can create a remote session to the server and work as if you were locally on the Exchange box. Otherwise, you need to install the Exchange admin tools on your machine.